# colorbar with a slider using wxpython

Tags: python, slider, wxpython, color-mapping

I haven't seen an example of this but I wanted to know if any knows how to implement a colorbar with an adjustable slider using wxpython.  Basically the slider should change the levels of the colorbar and as such adjust the colormap.
If anyone has an idea of how to do and possible some example code it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you want.  Maybe a picture would clarify.  Does the slider specify the position on the colorbar or change the whole colormap.  Usually a colorbar is a representation of a colormap (showing which colors correspond to which values), so a slider specifying the position on the colorbar wouldn't change the colormap.

Comment: I don't have an exact picture of what I want, but bear with me as I try to explain what I want.  Essentially what I want is to allow the user to manually adjust the colormap, so it would be like changing a certain threshold value or range of a colormap. My idea for this originally was to incorporate a slider that the user could use to adjust the threshold value and change the display on the colormap.  The slider should be used to specify a position on the colorbar and as such change the whole colormap.  Please let me know if this clearifies things.

Comment: I am open to other suggestions as to how this can accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for one of the following widgets:

ColourDialog, ColourSelect, PyColourChooser or CubeColourDialog

They all let you choose colors in different ways and they have a slider to help adjust the colours too.

You can see each of them in action in the wxPython demo (downloadable from the wxPython web page)

Comment: Thanks.  This seems to be what I was looking for.